# Self-adjointness of the components of the magnetic derivative

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, operator-theory, schrodinger-operators

On $L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ define the operator $\Pi_{j} u := (-i\partial/\partial x_{j} - A_{j})u$, where $A_{j} \in L^{2}_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$ represents the $j$-th component of the magnetic potential on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $u \in Dom\ \Pi_{j} := \{ u \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{n}) \ \vert\ -i\partial u/\partial x_{j} - A_{j}u \in L^{2}(\mathbb{R}^{2}) \}$, where $\partial u/\partial x_{j}$ is the weak derivative of $u$.

I wish to understand what sort of conditions on $A_{j}$ ensure that this operator is self-adjoint.

Comment: You cannot use positivity, hence a result like the Kato inequality for the laplacian is not possible. With perturbation theory you can prove self-adjointness, i.e. if there is $a<1$ s.t.
$$\lVert A_j \psi\rVert\leq a \lVert \partial/\partial x_j \psi\rVert +b\lVert \psi\rVert\; .$$

Answer (score 1):

If you introduce the functions $a_j:=\int A_j dx_j$ and the unitary operators $(U_j f)(x):=e^{-ia_j(x)}f(x)$, then you can write $\Pi_j=U_j^* D_j U_j$, where $D_j=-i\partial/\partial x_j$ with the standard domain, and $D_j$ is self-adjoint. So my impression is that $\Pi_j$ is self-adjoint for any real-valued $A_j\in L^1_\text{loc}(\mathbb{R}^n)$.